# Complex maximization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

i would like to solve the following system:

```
c[e_] := 1/2*e + 1;
d[y_, x_] := x*y^2;

e[y_] := NMinimize[{Integrate[PDF[BetaDistribution[2, e], x]*d[y, x] + c[e]
    , {x, 0, 1}], e >= 0}, e]

U[z_, y_, p_] := p - Integrate[PDF[BetaDistribution[2, z], x]*d[y, x] + c[z], {x, 0, 1}]

NMaximize[{y - p, U[e[y], y, p] == 0, y >= 0, p >= 0}, {y, p}]
```

Do you see what i messed up?

PS: I try to maximize y-p given the constraint U[e[y], y, p] == 0

Comment: You're trying to `Maximize an equation? Or are you trying to `Maximize `y-p` subject to constraints? Either way, you're lacking curly brackets.

Comment: I try to maximze y-p. I included the brackets now

Comment: One error I'm spotting in your code is that you're re-using variable in places where you shouldn't. For example, the variable `e` is used as both a function and as the optimization variable in `NMinimize`. Furthermore, `NMinimize` doesn't return just a number but also a `Rule` containing the position of the minimum, so you need to pull out the right answer before you can insert the result into other functions.

Comment: you are actually re-utilizing the symbol `e` for three different things. While that may or may not be an actual problem it sure makes things hard to follow. Is `e[y]` intended to be the *minimum value* or the value of the local `e` at the minimum?

Answer (score 2):

both of your integrals can be done analytically with appropriate assumptions, note the way I formulated things both integrals are in non-delayed defintions.

```
c[eloc_] = 1/2*eloc + 1;
d[y_, x_] = x*y^2;
f[e_ /; e > 0, y_] = Assuming[{0 < x < 1, e > 0},
   Simplify[
    Integrate[Simplify[PDF[BetaDistribution[2, e], x]*d[y, x] + c[e]],
     {x, 0, 1}]]];
efun[y_?NumericQ] := e /. NMinimize[{f[e, y], e >= 0}, e][[2]]
(* this is the value of e that minimizes f *)
U[z_ /; z > 0, y_, p_] = p - Assuming[{0 < x < 1, z > 0},
   Integrate[
    PDF[BetaDistribution[2, z], x]*d[y, x] + c[z], {x, 0, 1}]]

ContourPlot[ U[efun[y], y, p] == 0, {y, 0, 2}, {p, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

I'd suggest you review this and make sure its right..

```
FindMaximum[{y - p, U[efun[y], y, p] == 0, y > 0,   p > 0}, {{y, 1}, {p, 1}}]
```

> {-0.75, {y -> 0.5, p -> 1.25}}